# Sort a List<String> that includes date values by date

Tags: c#

I am working on a time clock program and I am having an issue getting my time punches to be in the correct order. The dates are in order, but the list.Sort() is putting the times out of order. It is sorting it like a string, which make sense because it is a string. 3:41PM is sorted before 7:20AM because 3 is before 7. See example:

```
 12/17/2018 3:41:00 PM         Clock Out         Yes            BB  
 12/17/2018 7:20:00 AM         Clock In          NO             Not Needed
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this because of the information I am dumping into the list.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     timeClockDataList.Add(reader["Punch"].ToString() + "%" + reader["PunchType"].ToString() + "%" + reader["NeedsApproval"].ToString() + "%" + reader["Approval"].ToString());
}
```

I am putting the "%" in there so I can split the string at the % later to populate the time card with the punch time, type of punch, approval needed, and approval.

My question is how to sort this string by the Date AND Time?

***EDIT***

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    timeClockDataList.Add(new ClockData
    {
     Punch = DateTime.Parse(reader["Punch"].ToString()),
     PunchType = reader["PunchType"].ToString(),
     NeedsApproval = reader["NeedsApproval"].ToString(),
     Approval = reader["Approval"].ToString(),
   });

//***This is the old code that makes one long string***
//timeClockDataList.Add(reader["Punch"].ToString() + "%" + ToString() + +                      
}

timeClockDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Punch);
//***This is the old code that would sort the list string***
//timeClockDataList.Sort();    

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    for (int _i = 0; _i < timeClockDataList.Count; ++_i)
    {
         punch = timeClockDataList[_i].Punch.ToString();
         punchType = timeClockDataList[_i].PunchType;
         needsApproval = timeClockDataList[_i].NeedsApproval;
         approval = timeClockDataList[_i].Approval;

         writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-5}{1,-30}{2,-20}{3,-11}{4,-15}", "     ", punch, punchType, needsApproval, approval));

            punch = null;
            punchType = null;
            needsApproval = null;
            approval = null;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Why not make a list of objects containing the datetime and punch type instead of making a string you have to parse later?

Comment: Create a class that holds all the 4 variables in their original format and use that for your `List`. Then add a new instance of that object to your `List` Assuming that's a possibility. Then you can just use `OrderBy(x => x.Punch)` where `Punch` is the variable that holds the `DateTime`

Comment: Create a class for the fields is the best choice. For some unknown reason if you have to keep it in string format, try formatting the time to be HH:mm format so it'll be 15 hrs instead of 3 pm.

Comment: In addition to what others have commented/answered: If this is a DataReader then you should 1) Specify the returned columns in the query and 2) Read the types in their native format instead of converting them to a string and then parsing them again. Example: [reader.GetDateTime(0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_IDataRecord_GetDateTime_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`timeClockDataList` is the wrong type.  When everything is one big string then you don't have data, you just have one big string.

Make a custom object to store your data.  For example:

```
class ClockData
{
    public DateTime Punch { get; set; }
    public string PunchType { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Read your data into a list of that class:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    timeClockDataList.Add(new ClockData
    {
        Punch = DateTime.Parse(reader["Punch"].ToString()),
        PunchType = reader["PunchType"].ToString(),
        // etc.
    });
}
```

Now you have actual data, which can be manipulated/sorted/etc. easily:

```
timeClockDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Punch)
```

You may also want to throw in some error checking when populating it, use `TryParseExact` for the `DateTime`, etc.  There are a variety of improvements you can make.  Eventually, when you want to *display* the data, *that's* when you output it as a string.  (You can make that very simple by overriding `.ToString()` on the custom class.)

Comment: This makes it much easier having he ClockData to put my information in. However it still is not sorting my Time Card correctly. I still have information out of order and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. I am fairly new at writing code (only a few months) and I really appreciate your help with this issue I am having.

Comment: @BrettByrd: If you're sorting by actual `DateTime` values (not strings) then it should sort correctly.  What's out of order?

Comment: Looking at each line of the time cards it hasn't changed the order at all. I even went back to the first of this month and it has dates all over the place. Most of them are in order but, for example, a lot of Dec 17th punches are put right in the middle of the Dec 18th punches on the print out. Like I said i am fairly new and don't really know where I've messed this up.

Comment: @BrettByrd: Well, I can't see your code so there isn't much I can do right now.  Perhaps you can edit the question to include the updated information?

Comment: I can do that so I can show more code. I did change it to where I was only getting the Date from the database and it put it in the same order (mind you they all said midnight) but the dates were still all out of order.  I will try and post the code in a second.

Comment: I added how I use streamwriter and the reader in an edit. Also is this how I should make my list now: `List<ClockData> timeClockDataList = new List<ClockData>();`

Comment: @BrettByrd: This doesn't sort in place: `timeClockDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Punch);`.  You need to assign the result: `timeClockDataList = timeClockDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Punch);`

Comment: It keeps giving me this "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<EmployeeDatabase.ClockData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EmployeeDatabase.ClockData>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @BrettByrd: You may need to add a “.ToList()” after the OrderBy call then.  Be careful with things like that though.  While it may make no difference in this code, if you ever move to Entity Framework (which you should) or other tings which build expression trees, that will fully materialize all the backing data when you may not want that.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I am literally just teaching myself how to do this from a very large book and Stackoverflow and I take any input and help very seriously. 

***IT WORKS!!!***
I have been working on this all day (7am -now) trying to get these time cards in the correct order. You have been a lot of help and I very sincerely appreciate your help. Have a Merry Christmas!